# "Книга" в смысле "произведение"

Tags: грамотная-речь, стилистика

Можно ли написать, например, «Книга Толстого "Война и мир"» вместо «Роман Толстого "Война и мир"»?

Answer (score 1):

Так *можно* написать, однако обычно требуется определённый *контекст*, чтобы сослаться на художественное произведение как на "книгу" и при этом не привлечь излишнего внимания к особенностям собственного самобытного стиля (принято называть жанр худ. произведения, а не очевидный тип "носителя информации"). Например, речь может идти о выделении *одной из "книг" автора* в ряду его художественных произведений разных литературных жанров (каждое его произведение задумывалось или издавалось как книга; в одном случае это это роман, в другом - сборник рассказов, стихов и т. п.). Нужно учитывать и то, что "Война и мир" - четырёхтомник. Но вполне нормально, например, *главной книгой Толстого считать "Войну и мир"*.

Проще обстоит с "книгами", написанными не литераторами и не учёными (с их "книгами" похожая история: учебники, монографии, трактаты и пр.) - книги таких "необычных" авторов не принято сразу называть по жанрам (мемуары, воспоминания); зачастую *факт написания книги* человеком иного рода занятий - это *новая информация* о нём самом, поэтому в порядке вещей сначала сообщить о факте написания книги (его книга под таким-то названием), а потом уже уточнять её жанр (иногда это художественное произведение). При этом, если уточнения не последует, адресатом книга будет мысленно отнесена к документальному жанру.

Таким образом, можно сказать, что в отношении людей, которые *заведомо пишут "книги"*, сложившийся нейтральный стиль упоминания о книге требует называть её по жанру.

Answer (score 0):

Выражение типа "книга писателя" неоднократно встречается в Нацкорпусе. Мо-моему, скорее всего подразумевается изданное произведение, что в некоторых случаях мало отличается от выражения "произведение писателя".

Вот некоторые примеры из Нацкорпуса.

Для того чтобы книга писателя N, которая получила премию имени Х, вошла в чтение достаточно широких слоев читательской аудитории
[Валерия Стельмах, Ирина Николаева. Кафедра жизни // «Октябрь», 2001]

Главная **книга** писателя ― «История моего современника». [Страна далекого детства // «Трамвай», 1991]

(«История моего современника» — итоговое **произведение** Владимира Галактионовича Короленко. [http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ruwiki/391158])

В том же ключе была написана и предыдущая **книга** писателя «Я, бабушка, Илико и Илларион». [М. Долинский, С. Черток. Я вижу солнце // «Советский экран», 1965]

(«Я, бабушка, Илико и Илларион» — **роман** Нодара Думбадзе [[https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AF,*%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%B0,*%D0%98%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE_%D0%B8_%D0%98%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD_(%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AF,_%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%B0,_%D0%98%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE_%D0%B8_%D0%98%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD_(%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD)) ])